# Is there a way to check the data type of a context variable in Jinja2?

Tags: django, jinja2

I am trying to check the Type of context variable on a Jinja2 template, on a Django app.
I am trying to check if the variable `result` is of type `<SearchResult: myapp.B (pk=u'1')>` or `<SearchResult: myapp.A (pk=u'1')>`.

Here's the Code I am trying to implement.

Context = 'results':form.search()}

X.html

```
{% for result in results %}

     <!-- if result is a SearchObject of B -->
     {% ifequal result 'SearchResult: myapp.B' %}
     <div class="container">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="/B/{{ result.pk }}" class="list-group-item">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ result.title }}</h4>
                <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">Created on: {{ result.createdon }}     </h6>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endifequal %}
```

{{result}} prints this `<SearchResult: myapp.B (pk=u'1')>`. So, for 2 types myapp.A and myapp.B, I want to apply two separate pieces of code. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `{% ifequal result.model_name 'A'%}`